# Strange Alignment in UITextView

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

Trying to create a new UITextView in a new project and set the alignment to center through storyboard it appears to has a bug.

**First image I write three lines:**

**Second image I start a new paragraph and the cursor goes to left, why?**

[image]
[image]

Comment: what is the textview alignemnt set to ?

Comment: what are you trying to do ?

Comment: already u asked the same question in yester day also , still now you are not get the answer

Comment: Trying to set Text Alignment to center @Mr.T

Comment: where did u set it ? in storyboard ?

Comment: Yes. Read the question.

Comment: what happens after you type on the new paragraph? Text still appears on left ?

Comment: could you show the delgate methods ?

Comment: No delegate methods you can simulate the issue with this step: -open xcode - new project - put a textview inside the main view - set the alignment to center through storyboard - write three or more lines and start a paragraph between the lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because, when you go back and go to new line, you breaking the text alignment. By default the text alignment is set to left.

To change this behaviour: set the text alignment to center, in the following delegate method , so that text always be in center mode, even when the text alignment mode is changed accidentally elsewhere in your code.

```
#pragma text view delegate method
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range replacementText:(NSString *)text{
  textView.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I've already tried your fix. But when you start a new paragraph the cursor still on the left until the user write some text

Comment: Yes. I agree. It is because at the point we set the text alignment to center, the previous text alignment is already broken, the new text alignment will be set after we type something.  I will see if there is any way to set the textview attributes after we press the return key.

Comment: in the meantime I select your answer as right. vote up if you find something to check the textview attributes after return key